# How to use tensorflow eager execution only in specific parts of the application?

Tags: tensorflow, darkflow

I've got few files with different files:

- main.py
- watch.py
- read.py
- detect.py <-- Uses tensorflow based library
  `darkflow` that relies on the graph mode
- translate.py  <-- uses tf
  eager execution

During darkflow's TFNet initialization I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/justin/Projects/comp3931/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    watcher = Watcher('res/vid/planet_earth_s01e01/video.mp4', 'res/vid/planet_earth_s01e01/english.srt')
  File "/home/justin/Projects/comp3931/watch.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.detector = Detector()
  File "/home/justin/Projects/comp3931/detect.py", line 6, in __init__
    self.tfnet = TFNet(self.options)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/darkflow/net/build.py", line 75, in __init__
    self.build_forward()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/darkflow/net/build.py", line 105, in build_forward
    self.inp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, inp_size, 'input')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1677, in placeholder
    raise RuntimeError("tf.placeholder() is not compatible with "
RuntimeError: tf.placeholder() is not compatible with eager execution.
```

So, I assume that when I instantiate `Translator` class from `translate.py` file it invokes eager execution on the whole program, which then is not compatible with calls to darkflow's `TFNet` class used in `Dectector` class from `detect.py`

If I run `translate.py` independently from others it works fine, other modules also work fine if run them without `translate.py` involved.

I guess the fact that they use different contexts (graph/eager), the whole thing can't run together in the same program. I've tried looking at the documentation, but could not find a way to switch back to graph mode when needed.

Is there any way I can run both eager and graph modes in the same application in different places?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is best to write code that's compatible with both graph mode and eager execution. From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/eager):

> - Use tf.data for input processing instead of queues. It's faster and easier.
> - Use object-oriented layer APIs—like tf.keras.layers and tf.keras.Model—since they have explicit storage for variables.
> - Most model code works the same during eager and graph execution, but there are exceptions. (For example, dynamic models using Python
>     control flow to change the computation based on inputs.)
> - Once eager execution is enabled with tf.enable_eager_execution, it cannot be turned off. Start a new Python session to return to graph
>     execution.

That said, it is possible to use eager execution while in graph mode by using `tfe.py_func()`. Here is the code example from the documentation (I just added the imports and asserts):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe

def my_py_func(x):
    assert tf.executing_eagerly()
    x = tf.matmul(x, x)  # You can use tf ops
    print(x)  # but it's eager!
    return x

assert not tf.executing_eagerly()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)
    # Call eager function in graph!
    pf = tfe.py_func(my_py_func, [x], tf.float32)
    sess.run(pf, feed_dict={x: [[2.0]]})  # [[4.0]]
```

The reverse is also possible, as Alex Passos explains in [this video](https://youtu.be/T8AW0fKP0Hs?t=788). Here is an example inspired by the one in the video:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe

tf.enable_eager_execution()

def my_graph_func(x):
    assert not tf.executing_eagerly()
    w = tfe.Variable(2.0)
    b = tfe.Variable(4.0)
    return x * w + b

assert tf.executing_eagerly()
g = tfe.make_template("g", my_graph_func, create_graph_function_=True)
print(g(3))
```

There's also an unofficial way to switch modes, using the `eager_mode` and `graph_mode` contexts defined in `tensorflow.python.eager.context` like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe
from tensorflow.python.eager.context import eager_mode, graph_mode

with eager_mode():
    print("Eager mode")
    assert tf.executing_eagerly()
    x1 = tfe.Variable(5.0)
    print(x1.numpy())

print()
with graph_mode():
    print("Graph mode")
    assert not tf.executing_eagerly()

    x2 = tfe.Variable(5.0)
    with tf.Session():
        x2.initializer.run()
        print(x2.eval())
```

As it is not official, you should probably avoid it in production code, but it may come in handy when debugging, or in a Jupyter notebook. One last option is to use this `switch_to()` function:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe
from tensorflow.python.eager.context import context, EAGER_MODE, GRAPH_MODE

def switch_to(mode):
    ctx = context()._eager_context
    ctx.mode = mode
    ctx.is_eager = mode == EAGER_MODE

switch_to(EAGER_MODE)
assert tf.executing_eagerly()
v = tfe.Variable(3.0)
print(v.numpy())
assert tf.get_default_graph().get_operations() == []

switch_to(GRAPH_MODE)
assert not tf.executing_eagerly()
v = tfe.Variable(3.0)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
assert len(tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()) > 0
with tf.Session():
    init.run()
    print(v.eval())
```

It is really a hack, but it may be useful in a Jupyter notebook, if you don't like nesting all your code in `with` blocks.

Answer (score -2):

https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/eager
(scroll down to "Use eager execution in a graph environment").

Maybe that helps...

Comment: That is not really an answer